# Import Jupyter Notebook dataframe to Google Sheets without shuffling rows

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

When I use `gspread_dataframe` and `gspread` to export data from a Jupyter Notebook to a Google Spreadsheet, rows are shuffled, which is not what I want. Can anyone help?

```py
emp_uniq = gspread_df['E_code'].unique() dict_e_code = {} x_df = pd.DataFrame() 

for emp in list(emp_uniq):
    dict_e_code[emp] = gspread_df[gspread_df['E_code']==emp]
    a = dict_e_code[emp][["Month","E_code","Allocation_ID","Project","Effective_days","Percentage_Util","Onsite/Offshore","Mapping","Payroll"]]
    a_fin = a.groupby(['Month','E_code','Project','Allocation_ID','Percentage_Util','Onsite/Offshore']).sum()['Effective_days']
    new_df = a_fin.to_frame().reset_index()
    new_df['Percentage_Util'] = (new_df['Effective_days']/new_df['Effective_days'].sum())*100
    x_df = x_df.append(new_df)
    x_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    x_df.drop(['index'],axis=1,inplace=True)


sheet = client.open(input("Please Enter Main Spreadsheet as Output Data: ")) worksheet_new = sheet.worksheet(input("Please Enter Sheet Name as Output Data:"))
existing = get_as_dataframe(worksheet_new) 
a = existing.append(x_df) 
gsdf.set_with_dataframe(worksheet_new, a)
```

Comment: Could you please post an example of the code you're using?

Comment: Please check the code edited in the body. @Burnash